# Change Kafka Streams configuration after compilation

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am currently working on a small Kafka Streams project with the goal to automatically set up a Kafka cluster and run a streams app on it. For convenience it would be very helpful if I could set the bootstrap.servers property outside of the .java file of the application, if possible even after compilation.

The documentation's only way to set properties is the following:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;

Properties settings = new Properties();
// Set a few key parameters
settings.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-first-streams-application");
settings.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka-broker1:9092");
// Any further settings
settings.put(... , ...);
```

But what if I don't know the hostname and port of the cluster yet when writing the code? The reason of this is that I want to create a tool that takes the configuration parameters of a Kafka cluster and a Kafka Streams application to then automatically set up all necessary VMs and services and execute the application. Someone else should be able to use this tool without having to change the Java code of the streams application.

Any ideas? The only other option I have in mind is parsing through the code and changing the property. If possible I'd like not to do that to unknown code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can always make the brokers and other configuration as runtime configuration. Infact that is the best practice to decouple the code with the cluster configuration since these configuration may subject to change.  You can create a `application.properties` or `application.yaml` file with all the runtime args.

**1.(With springboot) application.yaml example  :**

```
  application-id: my-application1
  bootstrap-servers:  server1:9092,server2:9092
  schema-registry-url: http://localhost:8081
  default-key-serde: String
  default-value-serde: JsonNode
  auto-offset-reset: earliest
  default-state-dir: /data/state
  num-threads: 4
```

And add code to read properties in following way :
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/

If you are using spring boot project, you can run your jar in following way with application.yaml

```
java -jar myjar.jar --spring.config.location=path-to-yaml-file
```

**2. ( Without Spring) application.properties**

```
java -cp ... -Dmy.app.properties=/path/to/app.properties mypackage.myclass
```

Then you can read the System properties.

```
String propertiesPath = System.getProperty( "app.properties" );
final Properties myProps;
if ( propertiesPath != null ){
     final FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream( propertiesPath );
     try{
         myProps = Properties.load( in );
     }finally{
         in.close( );
     }
}
```